# Generic method, using where T : base. Why is T not considered to be of concrete type when calling other methods?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm wondering what I'm missing here. When debugging I'm seeing e as an instance of SpecificException but the method call is matched to the signature with the base Exception. How come? And can I get around that without adding checks for the type in my LogException method?

```
public string LogException<T>(T e)
        where T : Exception
{
    string errorMsg = e.ToString();
    errorMsg += Details(e);
    return errorMsg;
}

public string Details(Exception exception)
{
     return "foo";
}

public string Details(SpecificException exception)
{
     return "bar";
}
```

Comment: Because of inheritance. All exceptions inherit from the `Exception` class...

Comment: Because `Exception` is the only type is can be sure of and logically resolved to, and its sure the input is of that type, somewhere down the line - but it knows nothing of that type specifically; if you need different behaviour for different types then a generic method probably isn't the right choice.

Comment: Based on the example shown, I'd recommend that you forget your "without adding checks for the type" requirement and just do it with `is` or `as`. I'd only agree that that'd be the way to go if there are, in reality, a large number (maybe 4 or more) of exception types. Note that you can also (most likely, but depends on the solution) remove the generics and simply use `Exception e`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overload resolution happens at *compile time*. At compile time, the compiler can't possibly know the *runtime type* of `e`. It only knows that `e` will be of type `Exception` or a type deriving from it.
It doesn't know the concrete type, so the only correct overload to use is that for `Exception`.

To be able to achieve your goal, you can employ the DLR via the `dynamic` keyword:

```
errorMsg += Details((dynamic)e);
```

That will move the overload resolution to the runtime and at that point in time, the actual type of `e` is known, so it can choose the overload best matching it.

Comment: Thanks, for both explanation and solution.